# Problema CORS con angular y glassfish

Tags: angular, java-ee, angular5, glassfish, cors

Tengo varios días con un problema de **CORS**, tengo mi back en un api Rest en Glassfish (JavaEE), y la app Angular consume esa api, evidentemente estan en distintos servidores por lo que es necesaria la sentencia **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** en las respuestas del Back, pero el unico verbo que me responde es GET, el resto de verbos me devuelven un error como este, en este caso estoy intentando un PUT:

> Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://localhost:8080/SupplyChainCinco/api/banco/5. (Razón: Cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no presente)

Si se dan cuenta, los verbos que fallan son todos los que reciben datos en el servidor, estoy utilizando **POSTMAN** para probar mis apis, en POSTMAN todos los verbos funcionan bien, pero cuando intento utilizar los verbos con Angular entonces me da el error de CORS en todos los verbos que no son GET.

Estoy utilizando **HttpClient** de **Angular5**, no estoy utilizando frameworks en el back, estoy utilizando Netbeans.

Por favor alguna idea de que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Tenes que habilitar CORS en el back. hiciste algo de eso?

Comment: Postman no tiene las mismas restricciones que el browser, nunca te va a saltar ese error. Si ya añadiste las cabeceras de Access-Control-Allow-Origin a tu backend, comprueba a qué verbos está respondiendo. Es posible que el browser esté enviando un preflight con el verbo OPTIONS y que tu backend sólo acepte GET, POST, PUT y DELETE

Comment: igual para responder esto necesitamos saber si por el lado del front utilizas solo apache u otra herramienta puede que con proxypass por ajp funcione , y habilitando otras cosas

Comment: Intenta lo que dice  @amenadiel. Probablemente no tengas PUT habilotado.

Comment: Insisto que lo que no tiene habillitado debe ser OPTIONS. En general HEAD está habilitado por defecto porque es un GET sin body, pero OPTIONS perfectamente puede no estar. Postman no envía un preflight pero podrías comprobarlo poniendo explícitamente OPTIONS en la petición

Comment: Una duda importante: ¿en producción estará todo en el mismo servidor? Lo digo porque usando Angular lo normal es usar un proxy inverso para ahorrarte el problema, y si en producción estará igual, no necesitas implementar CORS en backend

Comment: Hola a todos los que han escrito, no he respondido porque mi PC se daño y estoy reparándola, pero el proyecto que tiene que ver con este problema continua... la manera de habilitar CORS en el back lo he hecho seteando ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN  a "*" en la cabecera de mi respuesta en el servidor @gbianchi

Comment: @amenadiel me parece que el problema es por lo que mencionas, casi seguro que el problema es este pero nose como solucionarlo, como compruebo los verbos de respuesta del servidor ? y lo mas importante, como definito que el problema es de PREFLIGHT ??

Comment: @JackNavaRow si al final estará en apache seguramente, pero de momento esta en desarrollo la app y como es angular pues ejecuto la app con el CLI y corre en el servidor ligero que descarga el CLI al crear una app angular

Comment: @PabloLozano no, estarán en servidores separados, lo que hago es front con Angular y back con JavaEE y la comunicación a través de servicios REST, hasta ahora nunca he usado un proxy Angular

Comment: @RicardoGabriel ¿Con servidores te refieres a máquinas con IP distintas? Te lo comento porque habitualmente se suele poner un Apache/Nginx con un Tomcat/JBoss en la misma máquina, en puertos diferentes

Comment: @PabloLozano bueno, ve, en estos momentos yo tengo la arquitectura como la mencionas, front y back en localhost pero en puertos distintos, 4200 (angular) y 8080 (glassfish), pero sinceramente desconozco si mi cliente va a tener back y front en la misma pc, entiendo que no, pero que beneficio me trae ese proxy inverso ? me lo han mencionado pero para desarrollo, no para produccion

Comment: Cuando testeas tu app, en el navegador, en la pestaña desarrollo puedes ver en la consola los errores de cors, y en la pestaña de red los errores de los pedidos. compruebe ahi como funciona todo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que describes apunta a que no tienes habilitado el CORS en la aplicación en el servidor (servicio), esto lo resuelves habilitándolo (obviamente :P), para ello, si estas usando JEE, te puedo remitir a este [blog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/cors_for_jax_rs_2):

> La siguiente dependencia in un WAR instala y configura CORS
>   autmaticamente:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.airhacks</groupId>
>   <artifactId>jaxrs-cors</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.2</version>
>   <scope>compile</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> CORS es un proyecto opensource y licenciado con apache:
>   https://github.com/AdamBien/cors

En caso de no usar Maven, trata de descargar el JAR desde [aquí](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/airhacks/jaxrs-cors/0.0.2/jaxrs-cors-0.0.2.jar) y ponlo en la carpeta `lib` del Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

El navegador bloquea por defecto las peticiones JS que no proveengan del mismo origin.
La solución más sencilla cuando estes en desarrollo es que utilices un plugin para el navegador, en chrome hay uno que se llama CORS, con esto evitas ese error.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Cuando tu sitio se vaya a producción deben estar dentro del mismo dominio o configurar el servidor para que acepte peticiones desde el dominio donde va a estar alojado el frontend.